# How to move an element in Diagonal Movement in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I know how to move up and down an element in jQuery.

```
$("#div").animate({"left": "+=100"}, 1000); //move 100px to the right
```

But I have no idea to move in diagonal movement. I'm doing chess board and I don't know how to move Bishop with effect. Please have a look at following URL http://chess.diem-project.org/

I did like this... but it's not a proper way.

```
for(var i = 0;i<50;i++){ // move down and move right 1 pixel at a time to get effect
 $("#div").animate({"left": "+="+x}, 1); 
 $("#div").animate({"top": "+="+x}, 1); 
}
```

Any idea? Really appreciate your helps!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
 $("#div").animate({left: '+=50', top: '+=50'}, 1000);
```

You want one animation to get you there...a for loop queues 100 animations in your case, you just need the one :)  [See a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jdWRT/)

Comment: Exactly what I need. Amazing answer! Thank you so much Nick!